# Node.js expressjs fastest way to store and display a html page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, sendfile

I want to display a static HTML page with expressjs. What's the fastest way to do so? Currently I have a html file stored in the file system and I'm using `res.sendfile(home + "/public/file.xml")`

Is sendfile the fastest way to do it or might storing the file in some kind of database be faster?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing files in database? Well, some people try to do such *evil* things. But what is the point? I mean database engine has to read the file from disk as well. Additionally has to do many other things making the loading process longer.

Now you seem to confuse some things. Sending files is the same thing as sending any other response. **At some point you have to send the binary data**, so you cannot avoid using `res.send` (or any other form of it). This is of course if we are talking about Node.js, because you might consider serving files via *nginx*, which is probably the best static file server there is.

One last thing: if you still want to serve files via Node.JS, then you may consider caching them in memory. This of course depends on how many and how big files you want to serve. This is as easy as creating global variable which holds the data and sends it whenever there is a request. That's the only real performance boost you can make with Node.JS.

Comment: Well it's not the sending itself that I was asking about, more the storage. And yes the database in question would definitely store in memory.

Comment: But it does sound like sendfile is totally adequate for my needs so I'm fairly totally happy with that.

Comment: @Harry I see. Still using database for this is an overkill... and inefficient overkill. Simple solutions *really are* sometimes the best. :)

Answer (score 0):

Express has support for static file serving: `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`.

Comment: Yeah I know, is sendfile as fast as that? I believe it uses the same connect.static.send behind the scenes, so it should be the fastest way to serve a static page right?